# forEach for switch cases in Angular5 (TypeScript)

Tags: angular, typescript, foreach, switch-statement

I got a simple array of languages and a switch function. I cant find a solution to use forEach on the cases. (Would be helpfull because there are alot languages outside in the world) ;)

```
public languages = ["en", "de"];
public selectLanguage: string = "en";

changeLanguageSelect() {
    switch (this.selectLanguage) {
        case "en":
            this.translate.use('en');
            break;
        case "de":
            this.translate.use('de');
            break;
    }
}
```

There is not many more to say i think. I simply want to repeat with the `languages` array.

Comment: Why not just: `this.translate.use(this.selectLanguage)`

Comment: Actually, why not just `this.translate.use(this.selectLanguage)`? :)

Comment: Because i am a bad programmer :D Thanks alot! ;) But still interesting to know how t o repeat (foreach) in a switch. I dont find anything in google. maybe anyone can post an example for other peoples who google this.

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of allowed languages. Just check if current language exists in array then us it:

```
if (languages.includes(selectLanguage)) {
   this.translate.use(selectLanguage);
}
```

So, you dont need loop here

Comment: I just simplyfied for this post... its not just a array of languages in my case, its an array with multiple informations like id, name, icon url etc...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the language accept type of the browser to set which you are going to translate for the specific target of the person... Then have a select list of other languages and have them select it without having to use a switch.

The neat part would be hooking an angular into google translate... :)  I think you over complicate the issue what you have.   You could also use the pipe Internationalization (i18n) [Angular il8n docs](https://angular.io/guide/i18n)

Comment: Yeah i use ngx-translate and not the google translator =) I just want to get the browserlang later to set the default and save this into the localstorage. But i am a absolut beginner. Its the first time i try to code TypeScript or JavaScript.

Comment: Yes learn by doing...  I do the same , experiment with different tracks ...  you can get the language accept times from  navigator variable for the user.  The tough part is getting and testing foreign brower and language users to test your code..  Good luck